# How to get data shown out of workspace or directly from application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, gnome, swap

I'm a new user, because until this moment I used to handle with everything by myself. My problem is complex so I think I chose the right section. Because of some reason I had to use another web browser than my main which I use daily and I chose a small browser which I installed long time ago. This brower is called Dooble, version 0.07 (dooble-0.0+svn874) and I have been used it about 2 weeks. In this period of time I opened a lot of sites which I need to open again in future so I need a browsig history, but I checked before start of using it that it keeps the history so I was calmed down. Now I would like to get an access to the history and save it or export or just see, but there is a problem with it. The history is shown on a list which is in menu bar like File, Edit or Help. The list is too large to display it on the visible workspace. It rolls down to the end of the workspace and then to the right with no limit (just go out from the screen) and about 95% of content is out of visible part of workspace, so I can't see the history although the browser keeps it. So I decided to get it in other way. I was looking for the history on the disk space because I suspected that it may be stored in file. I checked the list of using files generated with command "lsof" and there is no file connected with Dooble. I also searched in ram memory, I copied an image of ram and opened in hex editor and looked for appriopriate string with no results. An idea to take a screenashot of an active window is also wrong because it tooks only a visible part. There is no possibility to change a resolution of a display in my case. I suppose that browser may encrypt the history stored in ram, like it does in the current version, but my version is very old (2008 probably) and I have no documentation or help files to this with specification. Moreover I use swap, but I can't read its content. The swap is a file and when I copy it and open like the image of ram there is nothing inside except zeros - the file is full of zeros although swap is full in some part which I can see typing "free" in terminal. Here is the source of this version: http://dooble.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.0plus-psvn874-0ubuntu2/dir_9cc8d803eb63e208c05c995ec1941f6c.html , I'm not programmer and don't understand it but maybe it whould be helpful in finding any solution, if so tell me please how can I use it. I use Ubuntu and Gnome. I can't close the broser and obviously system because the history will be deleted permanently. I really believe that there are people here who know what to do in my case. I'm not good in IT, so I will appreciate every hint. I really need your help! Ana

Comment: Please don't cross-post. [UL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97421/23363), [AU](http://askubuntu.com/q/365044/88802)

Answer (score 0):

So I dug through the source code of your version.

They use the Qt Framework and use QWebHistory is the part we care about specifically.

I dug up the source code for QWebHistory and it only saves to a file if you pass the data to a buffer in QDataStream.

They don't include QDataStream in any of the files you provided.

It doesn't appear the data is encrypted but it's possible.

It looks like you're just out of luck basically.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is very helpful because now I know where not to search. I really appreciate your support. But maybe I've got a bit of luck, because I'm very close to solve it (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97421/how-to-get-data-shown-out-of-workspace-or-directly-from-application). Thank you once again.